# Can't use JOIN with related entities in doctrine2

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was [guided by this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins), and I can't understand what's going wrong.

My entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="term")
 */
class Term {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Description", mappedBy="term")
     **/ 
    private $description;

    //....
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="description")
 */
class Description {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @Orm\ManyToOne(targetEntity="term", inversedBy="description")
     * @Orm\JoinColumn(name="term_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/  
    private $term;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8)
     */
    private $normativity;
    //...
}
```

I need to get terms and filter terms descriptions by one of it fields (normativity in example).

I tried this:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT term, desc FROM myTerminologyBundle:Term term
        JOIN term.description desc
        WHERE term.word LIKE :r_word' and desc.normativity IN :norm"         
    )->setParameter('r_word', '%'.$word.'%')->setParameter('norm', array());
```

and I get the following exceptions:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 30: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable
>   | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got
>   'desc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are reserved word **desc** in SQL. I change it to another and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
createQuery("
    SELECT term
    FROM myTerminologyBundle:Term term
    INNER JOIN myTerminologyBundle:Description desc
    WHERE term.word LIKE :r_word' and desc.normativity IN :norm"         
)
```

Comment: i haven't even try this, but looks like in your query i'll get Description entity? I need Term, whose Descriptions have normativity = somevalues

Comment: i got [Syntax Error] line 0, col 130: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

Comment: Which attributes of Term do you need?

Comment: I need whole Term entity. I need Term with filtered Descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use dql

```
$query= $this->getEntityManager()
                        ->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select('term.id as id,term.name as name')
                        ->from('FROM myTerminologyBundle:Term ', 'term')
                        ->innerJoin('term.Description ', 'desc')
                        ->Where('term.word LIKE=:term')
                        ->setParameters(array('term' => $term))
                         ->orWhere('desc.normativity  IN(:category_id)')
                        ->setParameter('category_id',$category_id)

                        ->getQuery();
             return $query->getResult();
```